# Charged isolated conductor field and gauss law confusion

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

In my textbook, it’s written that an isolated charged conductor can have no field inside it, as it would make the conduction electrons move around, creating a perpetual current generator.

So, now my question is, what if we remove all the conduction electrons are removed, then can a field exist within a spherical conductor?

Comment: if all conduction electrons are removed, it would becomes insulator.

Comment: I didn’t understand. Can you please explain?

Comment: the conducting e make the conductor to a conductor, without then it would be an isolator, but also if you could take away all e the charge of the conductor would by enormous